# Соответствие столбцов в двух фреймах данных

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть два неравных между собой фрейма данных. В одном тысяча строк (`df1`), в другом несколько (`df2`)).

```
df1 

Data number act1
2020 1      0
2019 4      0
2018 4      0
2017 5      0
2016 2      0
2015 5      0
```

```
df2

number act2
1      0
2      Yes 
3      0 
4      Yes 
5      0
```

Как записать значения для каждых `act1` из `df1`, значениями столбца `act2` из `df2` чтобы это все соответствовало общим `number`?

```
df1 

Data number act2
2020 1      0
2019 4      Yes 
2018 4      Yes 
2017 5      0
2016 2      Yes 
2015 5      0
```

Comment: Можете удалить из df2 строку с индексом 5 и показать какой результат ожидается в этом случае? И почему в результирующем фрейме столбец называется `act2`, а не `act1`?

Comment: задачу решили, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [35]: df1["new"] = df1["number"].map(df2.set_index("number")["act2"])

In [36]: df1
Out[36]: 
   Data  number  act1  new
0  2020       1     0    0
1  2019       4     0  Yes
2  2018       4     0  Yes
3  2017       5     0    0
4  2016       2     0  Yes
5  2015       5     0    0
```

PS я специально для наглядности присвоил результат в новый столбец. В реальной задаче можно присвоить его обратно:

```
df1["act1"] = df1["number"].map(df2.set_index("number")["act2"])
```

результат:

```
n [40]: df1
Out[40]: 
   Data  number act1
0  2020       1    0
1  2019       4  Yes
2  2018       4  Yes
3  2017       5    0
4  2016       2  Yes
5  2015       5    0
```

Comment: `df1.merge( df2, on='number')` ?

Comment: @splash58, там придется потом городить огород, чтобы собрать все в один столбец...

Comment: я в ответ положил, вроде, тоже самое

Comment: @splash58, возможно я неправильно понял вопрос - посмотрим что ответит автор на уточняющие вопросы

Answer (score 2):

```
df1.merge( df2, on='number')
   Data  number  act1 act2
0  2020       1     0    0
1  2019       4     0  Yes
2  2018       4     0  Yes
3  2017       5     0    0
4  2015       5     0    0
5  2016       2     0  Yes
```